# range data in rviz

Tags: ros, rviz, range, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i want to test my ultrasonic sensor,

i am trying to see them in rviz as range, but there is nothing

here is my 'rostopic echo /sensor_us' :

```
header:
  seq: 53
  stamp: 
  secs: 1565946432
   nsecs: 420665979
  frame_id: "range_sensor_frame"
radiation_type: 0
field_of_view: 0.347999989986
min_range: 0.239999994636
max_range: 0.800000011921
range: 25.0
```

rviz parameters:

```
unreliable: off
color: red
alpha: 0.5
buffer/length: 1
queue size: 100
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/330870/range-data-in-rviz/) by [june2473](https://answers.ros.org/users/44408/june2473/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2019-08-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

this seems odd:

```
max_range: 0.800000011921
range: 25.0
```

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [june2473](https://answers.ros.org/users/44408/june2473/) on 2019-08-16**:
thanks, it worked, now i see cone from range_sensor_frame, but i dont see obstacle

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-08-17**:
That would be a different problem, which should probably be diagnosed/answered in a separate question.